# Change button style for valums file uploader

Tags: asp.net, button, uploader

I use [file uploader](http://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader) in my asp.net project, I want to init this file uploader when I clik on link, but default it use template with button

```
 <div class="qq-uploader span12">
 <pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12">
  <span>{dragText}</span></pre>
 <div class="qq-upload-button btn-success">Select Picture</div>
 <ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>
 </div>
```

I changed div with class qq-upload-button into , but it not work because it need to have this class qq-upload-button,
how init uploader when I click on link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS for this. Try adding this to the `<head>` tag at the top of your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .qq-upload-button.btn-success {
        background: none;
        text-align: inherit;
        width: inherit;
        padding: 0;
        color: black;
    }
    .qq-upload-button.btn-success:hover {
        background: none;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

This will remove the button styling added by file uploader, and style the div like a link.

Comment: work ok, but I added "!important" in the end of every row, thx for help :)